# How to set Wordwrap in Excel using vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have looked at the solutions offered and have tried them with no luck. I feel I am missing something. I get the following error "Public member 'wordwrap' on type 'Worksheet' not found"

Thanks in advance.

Here is part of the code.

```
Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet1 As Object
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oBook = oExcel.workbooks.add
    oSheet1 = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    oSheet1.name = "ProjectPlan"

    oSheet1.Select
    oSheet1.Columns("C:C").Select
    With oSheet1
        .wordwrap = True
    End With
```

Comment: `With oSheet1.Columns("C:C")`

Comment: or `With oSheet1.Cells` for all the cells on that sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Sheet.UsedRange.WrapText = True
```

In your case:

```
Sheet.Columns("C:C").WrapText = True
```